# AIR for Android test movie strange behaviour

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, starling-framework

I am developing a Game for Android with Flash IDE I am also using Starling library. I have the following code in the Main.as:

```
var myStarling:Starling;
var viewPort:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,480,800);
myStarling = new Starling(Game, stage , viewPort);
myStarling.start();
myStarling.showStats = true;
myStarling.stage.stageWidth = 480;
myStarling.stage.stageHeight = 800;
```

When I hit `Control` + `Enter` the test movie window shows my game slightly displaced from top left corner.
I tested the same code on an other computer with flash CS6 installed. Now the whole test window is blank, but when I package it as APK it works fine on devices.
If I run the SWF outside of the Flash IDE it runs fine too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to manually set the alignment of the stage?

```
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
```